# Excel complicated lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have two sheets, one has UPC codes, names, and sizes. The other has a small portion of those names with sizes but no UPCs. I need to get the UPC numbers to fill the appropriate fields.

See photo:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSyi3.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula that works on one big assumption: that there is only ONE upc for each combination of Name (e.g., Shirt One) and Size (e.g., "Youth Small").

Enter this in K2 on Sheet1.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$11,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$E$1:$E$11=$C2)*(Sheet2!$G$1:$G$11="Youth "&K$1)*ROW(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$11)))
```

This formula, if the aforementioned assumption is true, will return the matching UPC for the appropriate article Name and Size. This formula can be filled across the row and down the column for other sizes and articles.

**Breaking down the formula:**
The heavy lifting is done by the `SUMPRODUCT` function. It checks each row on Sheet 2 for the matching Name and size. For each row, if a match is found, the row number is added. If no match is found, it adds 0. If the assumption that there is only one row that will match both criteria is true, then this will return the row number of the matching entry.

The `INDEX` function then returns the value from the UPC column at the row number returned by `SUMPRODUCT`.